# Submodular function minimization over integer lattice

Tags: reference-request, submodularity

Let $[k]=\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$.
A function $f:[k]^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is submodular if $f(x)+f(y)\geq f(\max(x,y))+f(\min(x,y))$ for all $x,y\in [k]^n$. Here $\max$ and $\min$ are applied coordinate-wise.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is known about the following.

Assuming a value oracle is given. Is there a strongly polynomial time algorithm to find a minimizer of $f$? For this I mean an algorithm with running time $p(n,k)$ for some polynomial $p$.

Such algorithm is known for submodular set functions (which is equivalent to the $k=2$ case).